# ValueError: day is out of range for month occuring in backtrader

Tags: python-3.x

Please help with this error, this is the error I am getting while feeding my own csv data to the backtrader.

data sample is as follows

[image: csv data sample]

I am new to python and the python community

error:

> C:\Python\python.exe C:\Users\harif\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\learning\dataframe1.py
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Users\harif\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\learning\dataframe1.py", line 32, in 
>       fromdate=datetime(2, 10, 2016),
>   ValueError: day is out of range for month
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

```
import backtrader as bt


# Create a subclass of Strategy to define the indicators and logic

class SmaCross(bt.Strategy):
    # list of parameters which are configurable for the strategy
    params = dict(
        pfast=10,  # period for the fast moving average
        pslow=30  # period for the slow moving average
    )

    def __init__(self):
        sma1 = bt.ind.SMA(period=self.p.pfast)  # fast moving average
        sma2 = bt.ind.SMA(period=self.p.pslow)  # slow moving average
        self.crossover = bt.ind.CrossOver(sma1, sma2)  # crossover signal

    def next(self):
        if not self.position:  # not in the market
            if self.crossover > 0:  # if fast crosses slow to the upside
                self.buy()  # enter long

        elif self.crossover < 0:  # in the market & cross to the downside
            self.close()  # close long position


cerebro = bt.Cerebro()  # create a "Cerebro" engine instance

# Create a data feed
data = bt.feeds.GenericCSVData(dataname=r'C:\Hard_Drive\Tick_Data\tickdata_2\sp.csv',
                               fromdate=datetime(2, 10, 2016),
                               todate=datetime(1, 10, 2019))
print(data)
# cerebro.adddata(data)  # Add the data feed

# cerebro.addstrategy(SmaCross)  # Add the trading strategy
# cerebro.run()  # run it all
# cerebro.plot()  # and plot it with a single command
```

Answer (score 1):

Date time object accepts values in this order.

```
datetime(year, month, day[, hour[, minute[, second[, microsecond[,tzinfo]]]]]
```

There are 2 ways of fixing this.

1. You can write the values in the correct order. eg: `datetime(2016, 10, 2)`
2. You can specify which value is what. eg: `datetime(day=2, month=10, year=2016),`

Comment: Thank you Sidharth, that helped. after I made a correction as per your suggestion, the other error now coming up is :      
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\backtrader\feeds\csvgeneric.py", line 114, in _loadline
    dt = datetime.strptime(dtfield, dtformat)
  File "C:\Python\lib\_strptime.py", line 565, in _strptime_datetime
    tt, fraction = _strptime(data_string, format)
  File "C:\Python\lib\_strptime.py", line 362, in _strptime
    (data_string, format))
ValueError: time data '2/10/2016' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S

Comment: can you share the code?

please upvote if you found it useful

Comment: Hi Siddharth, it's the same code as above except i have changed the this section of the code fromdate=datetime(year=2016, month=10, day=2),
                               todate=datetime(year=2019, month=10, day=1, ))

Comment: and can you please also tell me how to upvote you as I am new to all this and don't see a button to upvote anywhere.